# Why does function returns a Closure

Tags: dart

Why the `resultB` is not an `integer` but a `Closure`?

The main difference between `applyA` and `applyB` is that I moved the if condition inside.

The code is the following:

```dart
  dynamic applyA(dynamic x) {
  if (x is Function) {
    return (dynamic f) {
      return (dynamic y) {
        return f(x(y));
      };
    };
  } else {
    return (dynamic f) {
      return f(x);
    };
  }
}

dynamic applyB(dynamic x) {
  return (dynamic f) {
    return (dynamic y) {
      if (x is Function) {
        return f(x(y));
      } else {
        return f(x);
      }
    };
  };
}    

void main() {
  const one = 1;
  addOne(int x) => x + 1;
  addTwo(int x) => x + 2;
 
  final resultA = applyA(one)(addOne); 
  final resultB = applyB(one)(addOne);
  final resultC = applyA(addOne)(addTwo)(one);
  final resultD = applyB(addOne)(addTwo)(one);
  
  print('''
    A=$resultA
    B=$resultB 
    C=$resultC 
    D=$resultD
    ''');
```

Output:

```
    A=2  
    B=Closure 'applyB__closure' 
    C=4 
    D=4
```

I prepared a dartpad too, you can run the code here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=9d5df10fb4600963521c87f1b8d2e446

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the code, it can be clearly seen that `resultB` is not an integer but a closure because the return type of the `applyB` function is also a closure.

In `applyB`, if you carefully take a look, the closure itself is responsible for checking the type of `x` and calling the appropriate function. This closure is returned by the `applyB` function.

When you call `applyB(one)(addOne)`, it returns a closure that expects another argument `y`. When you pass one as the value of `y`, the closure checks the type of `x` and calls `addOne` with the appropriate argument. Since `one` is an integer, the closure calls `addOne(one)`, which returns `2`.

In distinction to it, `applyA` returns a closure that takes a fucntion as its argument, and when that function is called with an argument, it checks the type of `x` and calls the appropriate function. So `resultA` is just an integer, not a closure.

Comment: Its obvious now. Thank you I needed to read that,